# How do you get an embedded Jetty webserver to dump its interim Java code for JSPs

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

I keep running into this problem when debugging JSP pages in OpenNMS. The Jetty wiki talks about keepGenerated (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/KeepGenerated) in webdefault.xml but it seems unclear how this works in embedded setups.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is ages old, but I haven't found the answer anywhere else on the internet and it doesn't seem as though this has gotten any easier.  Hopefully this will help someone:

extract your webdefault.xml from the jetty-version.jar, mine was in :C:\Documents and 
Settings\JB.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jetty\jetty\6.1.22\jetty-6.1.22.jar inside the org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml file

Put the webdefault.xml into my project directory

Edit the webdefault.xml and add the following line:

```
<servlet id="jsp">
 ....
  <init-param>
    <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

Add the following into your maven pom.xml config:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>    
    <webDefaultXml>webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When you run the `mvn jetty:run` maven goal my jsp code is now kept in target\work\jsp\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jetty 6 you can use the following code:

```
String webApp = "./web/myapp"; // Location of the jsp files
String contextPath = "/myapp";
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext(webApp, contextPath); 
ServletHandler servletHandler = webAppContext.getServletHandler();
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(JspServlet.class);
servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(holder, "*.jsp");
holder.setInitOrder(0);
holder.setInitParameter("compiler", "modern");
holder.setInitParameter("fork", "false");

File dir = new File("./web/compiled/" + webApp);
dir.mkdirs();
holder.setInitParameter("scratchdir", dir.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing some housekeeping on questions I haven't yet answered. I'm afraid I never was able to get this to work but I think it's down to the "special" way OpenNMS starts up Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

It is dumped already.
for example if you have a file called `index.jsp`, a file will be created called `index_jsp.java`
Just search for something like that in the work directory.

Comment: Hmm, there are some ${page}_jsp.java files around but they don't seem to update when I change the related jsp page even though the results show up straight away on the browser.